# How to Speed Up Normalization in Encog.NET

Tags: c#, machine-learning, normalization, encog

I have the following code to normalize my document.  My document contains the following method to normalize my `SmallShuffledTrainingData` CSV.

```
static void Normalize()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Normalizing...");
    var analyst = new EncogAnalyst();

    var wizard = new AnalystWizard(analyst);
    wizard.Wizard(SmallShuffledTrainingData, true, AnalystFileFormat.DecpntComma);

    // customer id
    analyst.Script.Normalize.NormalizedFields[0].Action = Encog.Util.Arrayutil.NormalizationAction.PassThrough;

    var norm = new AnalystNormalizeCSV();
    norm.Analyze(SmallShuffledTrainingData, true, CSVFormat.English, analyst);
    norm.ProduceOutputHeaders = true;
    norm.Normalize(SmallShuffledTrainingDataNormalized);
    analyst.Save(AnalystFile);
}
```

I am only trying to normalize one column since it takes such a long time.

My document has 332k rows and 25 columns.

Is there anyway to speed up the normalization process other than breaking it down into smaller and smaller documents?

If I do break it down, how could I possibly combine them into one document being as the normalization needs to see all records to find the highest and lowest values of a given column?

Comment: Normalization on the dataset is altering all the dataset values, you have 332K and 25 columns. That would be iterating 332.000*25 and doing math operation on them. O(n) where n is 8.300.000. The normalization time scales O(n). What about caching the result if your data doesn't change? If you are curious, then the code can be analyzed here https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/blob/master/encog-core-cs/App/Analyst/CSV/Normalize/AnalystNormalizeCSV.cs

Comment: How do you mean, "cache the result?"  I don't see any caching going on in the source code you sent.

Comment: What i mean, cache the result of the normalized data, so it only run once. You would have to implement the caching method. Or normalize the data once and save the result to file. Then next time load the normalized data instead of loading your normal data and applying normalization.

Comment: The thing is, I can't even get my code to do a single run through - so I can't cache it at all since it won't even go through.  I waited over an hour and it still wasn't done.  Is there a better way to optimize this large of a file?

Comment: Sounds really slow, you could try to post it on Encog  http://www.heatonresearch.com/forum I would start to verify whether the API is used correctly and find out which part of the code that is slow. Is it norm.Analyze() or norm.Normalize() etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks!  The slowness was a "non-scaleability" issue during the analysis phase of the CSV wizard. This would show up on particularly large files.  I was able to reproduce the issue using your code above.  I just checked a fix for this into GitHub. You can see the commit here.

https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/commit/4f168c04cfd85d647f18dca5c7a2a77fff50c1e5

This will go into Encog 3.3 (which is not yet released).  But you can grab the fix from GitHub.  With this fix, I can normalize a similar sized file in just a few minutes.

Some other suggestions.

If you add this line:

norm.Report = new ConsoleStatusReportable();

You will get progress updates.

You also need to designate the prediction field, or you will run into an error later on.  Something like this:

wizard.TargetFieldName = "field:1";

Comment: Thank you!  In order to fix this on my end, I would have to download the source code, plus your code, and then recompile the DLL and replace my existing DLL with it?

Comment: Yes.  Just grab the code from here.  And select download zip.  Rebuild a release DLL and use that.  https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core

Comment: Thanks, it is definitely faster.  However, it won't normalize one particular column.  I have detailed the problem here [Why Won't Encog Normalize This Equalateral Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068481/why-wont-encog-normalize-this-equalateral-column) if you have time to help.

Comment: Nevermind, I neglected to notice there were some strange values in that column; so it must have confused Encog.